# md5sum on large files

Tags: bash, find, md5

Context:

I have a large terabyte drive with various types of large media files, ISO image files, etc. I would like to verify its contents using `md5sum` on the first megabyte due to speed/performance.

You can create a sum like this:

```
FILE=four_gig_file.iso
SUM=$(head -c 1M "$FILE" | md5sum)
printf "%s *%s\n" ${SUM%-} "$FILE" >>test.md5
```

How would you verify this as the first megabyte's signature is different
than the whole file's?

I've seen this done in other languages, but I am wondering
how to do it in [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29). I've experimented with various `md5sum -c` permutations involving pipes and whatnot.

---

Instead of using `md5sum -c`, would you have to recompute the hashes into a new file, then 'diff' them?

You can use a

```
find /directory/path/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum blah blah
```

to work on a large number of files.

PS: **Rsync is not an option**

UPDATE 2: So as it stands --

Using head, find, and md5sum; one could then create a file from the source directory fairly quickly, then check it with diff on the other side after computing on the destination. Are there clever one-liners or scripts for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To verify contents by only sampling the first megabyte of a file will likely not detect if some of the larger files have been corrupted, damaged or altered in one way or another. The reason for that is you're only giving the hashing algorithm one megabyte of data when there might be hundreds of other megabytes that could be off. Even one bit in the wrong position would give a different signature.

If data integrity is what you want to verify, you're better off with the CRC32 algorithm. It's faster than MD5. Although it it is possible to forge/modify a file to appear to have the correct CRC32 signature, it is not likely that random bits of corruption will ever do that.

**Update:**

Here's a nice one-liner to do the 1 megabyte based md5 checksum on every file:

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} sh -c "echo '{}' >> output.md5 && head -c 1M '{}' | md5sum >> output.md5"
```

Replace md5sum with cksum if you feel like it. Notice that I chose to include the filename in the output. That's because the filename string does not get passed on when you're not giving md5sum the whole file.

Comment: There is that risk, yes. The issue is the speed and performance of md5sum across a large capacity drive containing very large files. To checksum the entire file is not practical. Thank you for the CRC32 tip, I will definitely check into that.

Comment: Does the Linux command cksum use CRC32? Both man and info say 'CRC' but not CRC32.

Comment: Yes, cksum uses CRC32. There are a few variations of CRC32 (or CRC) which could be confusing if you were to compare checksums from other tools. Check out the wikipedia article for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: - Thanks! Good to know. I'll do some tests and weigh options from there. Since this is mostly to test the presence/absence of a file, 1 MB might be an OK risk as far as corruption. If CRC32 is fast enough though, maybe I don't need to take that risk.

Comment: used time with both md5sum and cksum - I show that cksum is _slower_ than md5sum.

Comment: I just tried it on a 3 gigabyte file and they were approximately using the same amount of time. If you really want to just check the presence of files, it's fairly easy to do so. I'll update my answer. Then you should probably do a long crunch to verify the integrity afterwards.

Comment: md5 and sha1 are likely to be I/O bound on any modern system, and have a much smaller chance of collision than crc32.

Comment: Nice one-liner! Thinking I might script this up to handle a directory and output file. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that there is an overhead caused by repeatedly launching the required utilities for each file, which would slow things down. A python script or similar would be a good option for this.

Comment: Could using `tail` instead of `head` be an improvement, since the beginning of a file is less likely to be corrupted than the end?

Comment: [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Answer (score 0):

A bit modified solution/example, using find -size argument to limit only files greater that 10M and computing md5sum from first 1M and last 1M portion of the file.

`find . -type f -a -size +10M -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} sh -c 'echo "$( (head -c 1M '{}'; tail -c 1M '{}' ) | md5sum) {} "'`

Comment: [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618). The other answer at least tries to quote the embedded `{}` in the shell code. I mean the outer double-quotes there will make the single-quotes get to `sh`. Your code closes the main quoting, uses `{}` and opens again; `sh` won't see any single-quote, unless from the expansion of `{}` (quotes and such from `{}` is exactly why you shouldn't embed). Both methods are flawed, but IMO your code is more flawed, even filenames with spaces will make it misbehave.